# Bash: Shell script with `read` command and def(s) wrapped within <<-EOF

Tags: bash, jq, eof

I have a question on how to provide a variable wrapped within **`'"..."'`**, the expected format for a value read by shell script using `read -d '' var <<- EOF`.

#### Overview

I wish to use this `jq` utility library: [jq-hopkok](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok). Specifically, bash shell script [to-components.sh](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok/blob/master/src/url/to-components.sh), which uses `jq` for parsing URL into its components.

This script is great, except, it is not clear to me how to use this script by passing it a variable `$URL`. It appears I can only pass this script with a static URL string that must be wrapped within **double-quotes** then wrapped again in **single-quotes**, e.g. **`'"..."'`**.

#### Example calling [to-components.sh](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok/blob/master/src/url/to-components.sh) with static URL value `'"https://..."'`

From [README.md](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok/blob/master/src/url/README.md):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# URL to components
echo '"https://server.example.com/deep/path/file.ext?with-a-parameter=true#and-a-fragment"' | ./to-components.sh
```

#### Example Partial Result

```
{
  "value": "https://server.example.com/deep/path/file.ext?with-a-parameter=true#and-a-fragment",
  "valid": true,
  "scheme": {
    "value": "https",
    "valid": true
  },
```

#### Reading URL string in [to-components.sh](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok/blob/master/src/url/to-components.sh)

The shell script [to-components.sh](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-hopkok/blob/master/src/url/to-components.sh) reads this **special-quoted URL string**, which must be wrapped `'"..."'` or it will fail to parse into components:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Split up a URL string to an object with the URL components.
read -d '' toComponents <<-'EOF' || true
...
EOF

cat | jq "$toComponents"
```

#### Desired Goal

I would like to call this shell script with a URL string with a variable, for example, I am not sure how to structure variable **`???${URL}???`** so that it can be parsed by shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
URL="https://server.example.com/deep/path/file.ext?with-a-parameter=true#and-a-fragment"

# URL to components
echo ???${URL}??? | ./jq-hopkok/src/url/to-components.sh
```

I have tried lots of approaches, but none work. All resulting with error:
`parse error: Invalid numeric literal ...`

#### Thank you

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo literal double quotes before and after `$URL`. A way to write this clearly is to create a variable that contains double quotes.

```
URL="https://server.example.com/deep/path/file.ext?with-a-parameter=true#and-a-fragment"
dq='"'
echo "$dq$URL$dq" | ./jq-hopkok/src/url/to-components.sh
```

Comment: this works perfectly! If you have time, then can you explain why? I have been pound my keyboard to come up with a solution.

Comment: `$dq` is a double quote. So this echoes a double quote, the URL, then another double quote.

Comment: I get it. Calling either `echo '"foo"'` or `URL="foo"  dq='"' echo "$dq$URL$dq"`, both return exactly the same result `"foo"`, which is why it works with this shell script starting with `read -d '' toComponents <<-'EOF' || true`. Thank you.